# Restarting kernel, ipython console in spyder

Tags: python, kernel, spyder

I am having this problem in spyder where, after I run my code and exit the gui.program, the kernel needs to manually be restarted after every time my code is ran, I sometimes even have to shut down spyder as kernel crashes. I am wondering if there is a way for the kernel to automatically be reset after closing the gui.program so I can run it again right after? This closes the program but doesn't restart the kernel.

```
    def EndProgram(self):
        
        print("Exiting Program")
        FigureCanvas.close(self)
        # behaviour to trigger on exit
        sys.exit()
        # exit
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There are two possible problems here: (1) If you're using a Spyder version older than 5.3.0, you need to [update](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases) because we fixed a lot of issues related to plotting during the last months; and (2) You don't need to use `sys.exit()` because it could cause an unnecessary restart in some operating systems.

Comment: I am currently using Spyder version 5.1.5, I tried to update it to 5.3.0, but that option wasn't available and says I have the most recent version. I am doing this through Anaconda. Should I install Spyder outside of Anaconda?

Comment: Have you tried to update conda?

Comment: I have just updated conda and the most recent version of Spyder I can see is 5.1.5 still.

Comment: What about creating a new environment from scratch? Maybe you have conflicting dependencies in the current one.

Comment: @Vic, please close Spyder, open the Anaconda Prompt or a system terminal, and run the following commands there: `conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge spyder`, `conda activate spyder-env`, `spyder`. That will allow you to run the latest Spyder because the one in Anaconda is very outdated.

Comment: I did that and everything is working good now! I had to change sys.exit(app.exec_()) to sys.exit() at the very end of my code as well. Kernel is now restarting perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, I had sys.exit() in my EndProgram() function as well as at the end of my code as seen here: sys.exit(app.exec_()). Once I took out the sys.exit() in my EndProgram function and changed sys.exit(app.exec_()) to sys.exit(), it is working perfect.

Original Code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 #   from LoadIceberg2 import LoadData2 
    app = Application(sys.argv)
    gui = ProgramGUI()

    qr = gui.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    gui.move(qr.topLeft())
#    app.processEvents()
    npics=8
    gui.show()

    # behaviour to trigger on exit
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

New code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 #   from LoadIceberg2 import LoadData2 
    app = Application(sys.argv)
    gui = ProgramGUI()

    qr = gui.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    gui.move(qr.topLeft())
#    app.processEvents()
    npics=8
    gui.show()

    # behaviour to trigger on exit
    sys.exit()
```